# como pasar Arraylist a otro activity Kotlin?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, hms-core

Buenas noches estoy tratando de pasar varios arraylist a otro activity pero manda en blanco, este es mi código de mi primer intent

```
var pathsList=ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>()//lista dela polilinea
var Listadatos=ArrayList<ArrayList<Steps>>() //lista que detalles de cada ruta
var endLocationsteep=ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>()//// lista para obtener el punto final de cada pas

val intent = Intent(this@Manejar, Empezar_manejar::class.java)
intent.putExtra("polilinea", pathsList)
intent.putExtra("cambios",Listadatos)
intent.putExtra("finpaso",endLocationsteep)
startActivity(intent)
```

mi segunda actividad  tiene el siguiente código

```
val polilinea = intent.getSerializableExtra("polilinea") as ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>
val cambios = intent.getSerializableExtra("cambios") as ArrayList<ArrayList<Steps>>
val finpaso = intent.getSerializableExtra("polilinea") as ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>

Log.e("polilinea:", polilinea.toString())
Log.e("cambios:", cambios.toString())
Log.e("finpaso:", finpaso.toString())
```

pero  no recibe nada , revise el log y me muestra asi:

```
E/polilinea:: []
E/cambios:: []
E/finpaso:: []
```

agradeceré me puedan ayudar

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, en tu pregunta no estas agregando valores a los ArrayList pathsList, Listadatos, endLocationsteep , lo estas realizando?

Comment: si los realize, esos datos de llenas gracias a un json. si lo imprimo con un log en la actividad 1 si se muestra todo, pero ya cuando deseo pasar a la segunda actividad no me muestra nada

Comment: Como estas llenando los array antes de enviarlos, eso debe ser el ùnico problema

Answer (score 1):

Es correcto como lo realizas, solo debes asegurar algo importante, los objetos deben implementar la clase Serializable:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Steps implements Serializable {
```

Comment: gracias. ya pude pasar los datos, ahora la consulta es como usar el primer,segundo, tercer....... valor  con el array list  solo ponemos->.get(1)**para saber el valor dela posicion 1,  y con el serializable como se realiza ?

Comment: Ah para saber el valor del elemento dentro del arrayList define el indice: get(indice) ,recuerda que inicia con 0 el primer elemento.